# Java Applet Closes IE for Users not Admins - where is JAVAPOLICY.EXE file?

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, applet

I have issue with Win2003 that Java Applet Closes IE for Users not Admins.

I found out the following solution but it refers to missing JAVAPOLICY.EXE file:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/J2SE/Q_22694925.html

where is this javapolicy.exe file, its not included with newest JRE6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find policytool.exe in

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin
```

The policy file is at

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\java.policy
```